# How can I make two or more images auto resize and not exceed bounding box?

Tags: html, css, resize-image

I want to place several images stacked horizontally and have them auto-resize and not break into two rows. In the example, I want both images toghether to fit within the 400px.
I've managed to do this with a table but it did not work very well in firefox so now I'm trying to do it the correct way. Auto-resize with height:auto;max-width:100% works with one image. This is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
<title>test</title>
<style>

    img {
        height:auto;
        max-width:100%;
        display:inline;
        float:left;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="border:1px solid red; width:400px;height:300px">
     <img src="img/test.jpg" width="800" height="100"/>
      <img src="img/test2.jpg" width="300" height="100" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you are trying to achieve :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/5KmGX/)**

I removed all the inline-styles that were setting withs and height to the images and breaking the layout and added this *CSS :*

```
img {
    height:auto;
    width:50%; /* specify 50% for 2 images, 33.33% for three images 25% for 4 images... */
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To have two images displayed per row, update your CSS to `max-width: 50%`. You can also try `max-width:49%` if 50% still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

try with max-width:200px; by  saying max-width:100%;you imply that the images are allowed to expand to 100% of the witdh of the container